# Is there anyway to break text with specific delimiter before using shingle token filter on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My stored data are like below:

`"quick fox jumps, slow goose runs, red sparrow"`

in

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'test',
  shorthand: 'quick fox jumps, slow goose runs, red sparrow'
  .
  .
  .
}
```

What I want to do is to first break this text based on , to have

`"quick fox jumps"`
`"slow goose runs"`
`"red sparrow"`

And then use `shingle token filter` (min_shingle_size: 2, max_shingle_size: 3) on `shorthand` field.

Expected tokens:
`quick fox`, `fox jumps`, `quick fox jumps`, `slow goose`, `goose runs`, `slow goose runs`, `red sparrow`

What is the proper way to handle this use case?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/csv-processor.html

Comment: can you share your expected tokens ?

Comment: @Amit Thanks. Added expected tokens to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be fulfilled by the `pattern` tokenizer and `shingle` filter on the produced tokens.

Use the inputs from these two wikis to achieve the results:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html